# How to stream web cam per ASP.Net Core WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, video-streaming, webapi

I try to create an endpoint which delivers a live stream of my webcam. I´m using AForge to access the camera, but I can´t manage to create and return a stream that actually renders in a video tag in the html client.

Additionally: The MemoryStream I'm using growes every second. And that is definitly not what I want.

What I tried so far:

Cam.cs:

```
public class Cam
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

    public Cam()
    {
        FilterInfoCollection videoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        VideoCaptureDevice finalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoCaptureDevices[0].MonikerString);
        finalVideo.NewFrame += this._streamNewFrame;
        finalVideo.Start();
    }

    private void _streamNewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image imgforms = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();


        imgforms.Save(this.stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);

        this.stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }

    public Stream GetStream()
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        this.stream.CopyTo(stream);
        return stream;
    }
}
```

CamController.cs:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class CamController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly Cam cam;

    public CamController(Cam cam)
    {
        this.cam = cam;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var contentType = "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=myboundary";
        Stream stream = this.cam.GetStream();
        var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, contentType)
        {
            EnableRangeProcessing = true,
            
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Update 1:**

I made progress. I managed to create a valid MJPEP stream (it is pretty easy if know how it has to look like). Look at that:

CamController.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace demo.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class CamController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly Cam cam;

        public CamController(Cam cam)
        {
            this.cam = cam;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("cam/video")]
        public async Task Get()
        {
            Response.ContentType = "video/webm";
            // How to go on here?            

        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("cam/mjepg")]
        public async Task Get2()
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 206;
            Response.ContentType = "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame";
            Response.Headers.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            

            StreamingSession session = this.cam.StreamOn(data =>
                {
                    if (Request.HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }

                    Response.Body.Write(this.CreateHeader(data.Length));
                    Response.Body.Write(data);
                    Response.Body.Write(this.CreateFooter());
                    Response.Body.Flush();
                });

            await Response.StartAsync();

            await session.WaitAsync();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create an appropriate header.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="length"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private byte[] CreateHeader(int length)
        {
            string header =
                "--frame" + "\r\n" +
                "Content-Type:image/jpeg\r\n" +
                "Content-Length:" + length + "\r\n\r\n";

            return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(header);
        }

        private byte[] CreateFooter()
        {
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Cam.cs:

```
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace demo
{
    public class Cam
    {
        object locker = new object();
        bool signaledToStop = false;
        List<StreamingSession> sessions = new List<StreamingSession>();
        VideoCaptureDevice finalVideo;

        public Cam()
        {
            FilterInfoCollection videoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            finalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoCaptureDevices[0].MonikerString);
            
            finalVideo.VideoResolution = finalVideo.VideoCapabilities
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.MaximumFrameRate)
                .ThenByDescending(x=>x.FrameSize.Width)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            finalVideo.NewFrame += this._streamNewFrame;
        }

        private void _streamNewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image imgforms = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            byte[] data = new byte[0];

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                imgforms.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                data = stream.ToArray();
            }

            lock (this.locker)
            {
                foreach (var session in sessions.ToList())
                {
                    session.ProvideData(data);
                }
            }
        }

        public StreamingSession StreamOn(Action<byte[]> callback)
        {
            StreamingSession session = new StreamingSession(callback);
            lock (this.locker)
            {
                this.sessions.Add(session);

                if (this.signaledToStop)
                {
                    this.finalVideo.WaitForStop();
                }

                if (!this.finalVideo.IsRunning)
                {
                    this.finalVideo.Start();
                    this.signaledToStop = false;
                }
            }

            session.OnSessionEnded += Session_OnSessionEnded;

            return session;
        }

        private void Session_OnSessionEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lock(this.locker)
            {
                this.sessions.Remove(sender as StreamingSession);

                if (!this.sessions.Any())
                {
                    this.finalVideo.SignalToStop();
                    this.signaledToStop = true;
                }
            }            
        }
    }

    public class StreamingSession
    {
        public StreamingSession(Action<byte[]> Callback)
        {
            this.Callback = Callback;
        }

        private Action<byte[]> Callback;
        private TaskCompletionSource Completion = new TaskCompletionSource();

        public event EventHandler OnSessionEnded;

        public Task WaitAsync(int? timeout = null)
        {
            if (timeout.HasValue)
            {
                return Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(timeout.Value), this.Completion.Task);
            }

            return this.Completion.Task;
        }

        public void ProvideData(byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Callback(data);
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                this.EndSession();
            }
        }

        public void EndSession()
        {
            this.Completion.SetResult();
            if (this.OnSessionEnded != null)
            {
                this.OnSessionEnded(this, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But there is a problem left: The "video" (more like moving images) only renders in an img tag. But it shall render in a video tag. I read that video tag doesn´t support mjpeg - **but how can I encode the stream in a format the video tag understands?**

I uploaded the complete code here: https://github.com/ChristophWieske/asp-net-core-live-stream-source

Comment: "renders in a video tag in the html client" what do you mean by that? You want to render  some textual information on video before sending it to client?

Comment: @eocron No, I simply want to display the video.

Comment: @christoph Show the client side as well.  Explain why `"multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=myboundary"` content type is being used

Comment: Until you write complete example, it is not easy for us to diagnose the problem. First thing you should do - write a test. Mock everything related to your cam driver (so everything is behind an interface, and no driver namespace is seen there) and provide your own implementation, which for example just repeats cat/dog image every 2 seconds. Then debug your app on it. Then switch back driver implementation.  That is what I would have done and fixated in unit tests.

Comment: @Nkosi I am not really sure about that, but it seems to be the correct choice for a mjpeg stream (which consists of multiple jpeg images -> so yeah bmp as image format is wrong, I will update that)

Comment: @eocron The images from the driver come easily. I saved some of them just to see whether they are actually correct. I see no need to mock my cam.

Writing a test is also pretty difficult for me as I don´t know how the stream returned by the webapi should look like. I can´t test a method which correct behavior I don´t know.

But you are right, I will prepare a complete sample on github to give you chance on running it yourself.

Comment: @christoph I pretty sure AForge do not support .Net core. Try to use  Emgu.CV example [here](https://www.dynamsoft.com/codepool/opencv-webcam-app-desktop-web.html)

Comment: See this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asynchronous-videos-live-streaming-with-asp-net-web-apis-2-0/

Comment: @user15119845 The sample you linked shows an approach to stream a video file - not a live stream. The real challenge in my question ist how I produce a stream of my live captured images.

Comment: @Alexrgs Actually it is working pretty good with Aforge. I suppose only on Windows but I am okay with that. But I will have a look into Emgu.CV - thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider WebRTC.

WebRTC is a relatively new browser based technology that allows a server to send streams to a JavaScript client.

See the WebRTC Samples for client side code:  https://github.com/webrtc/samples

Server side code is a bit more complex.  Here's an overly complicated example that uses "Mixed Reality."  It's a bit overboard, but should point you in the right direction.

https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/manual/cs/helloworld-cs-connection-core3.html

Comment: Hi RobV8R, I actually want to use the service as a laboratory video source. To consume the video stream no more than an a video tag with the correct source should be sufficient. Using a javascript client is not suitable for me.
(But I really will have a look into WebRTC, especially when I am going to stream from my client to the server)